# How to update UI via Handler

Tags: android, multithreading

So, I am getting an error that I am updating the UI from the wrong thread.  This of course was not my intention.  My case is quite long, but I will try to do it justice with code snippets.  My end goal is to run an expensive task in a separate thread and post update that happen along the way and at the end to my listView.

```
public class test extends Activity {

   private ArrayAdapter<String> _mOutArrayAdapter;
   private ListView _mOutView;
   private EditText _mCmdEditText;
   private Button _mRunButton;
   private Interpreter _interpreter;

   // Need handler for callbacks to the UI thread
   public final Handler _mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        _mOutArrayAdapter.add(msg.getData().getString("text"));
    };
   };

   // Create runnable for posting
   final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           updateResultsInUi();
       }
   };

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       _interpreter = new Interpreter(true);

       _mOutView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.out);
       _mCmdEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_command);
       _mRunButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_run);

       _mOutArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.message);
       _mOutView.setAdapter(_mOutArrayAdapter);
       _mOutArrayAdapter.clear();
       _interpreter.setOutputAdapter(_mOutArrayAdapter);

       Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
               _mResults = _interpreter.executeExpression("startup;",_mHandler);
               _mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
           }
       };
       t.start();

   );
```

And then inside inpterpreter I do this:

```
public class Interpreter 
{

    private static Handler _mHandler;

    public String executeExpression(String expression, Handler handler)
    {  
        _mHandler = handler;

        //Do a bunch of stuff that sometimes calls displayText from this class or from others

        return answer;
    }

    public void displayText(String text)
    {
        Message msg = new Message();
        Bundle bndl = new Bundle();
        bndl.putString("text", text);
        msg.setData(bndl);
        _mHandler.dispatchMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

The display of the final answer works.  And the dispatchMessage is ending up triggering handleMessage, but it throw an error that I cannot modify the UI from outside of the UI thread which I know is illegal. So, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Try and use Async Task and as others said, not sure what your code is doing

Comment: You're right, sendMessage is used to send messages that are received in handler's handleMessage.

Answer (score 3):

```
_mHandler.dispatchMessage(msg);
```

dispatchMessage() causes the Handler to be run on the current thread.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

> dispatchMessage(Message msg)
>
> Handle system messages here.

You should be using `_mHandler.sendMessage(msg);` It will put the message on the queue to be run by the Thread that declared the Handler.

> sendMessage(Message msg)
>
> Pushes a message onto the end of the message queue after all pending messages before the current time.

Comment: dispatch != send... what an obvious distinction /s. This only wasted hours of my time to track down why my handler wasn't working. Thank you Chris.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest you stick with an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (or one of the droid-fu versions if you need rotation/background support) unless you know what you're getting into. It'll help you cleanly keep track of what code is running in your UI thread and what code is in the background task, and save you a lot of confusion that dealing with `Thread`s and `Handler`s yourself can cause.

Comment: I have been looking into the trade offs with AsyncTasks vs. Threads.  Do you know why the example shown does not work though?

Comment: Your code is pretty messy, we really can't tell what's going on there. At least I can't

Comment: I am sticking with the Thread for several reasons.  I was hoping a simpler example would work to get help.  My problem was calling dispatchMessage instead of sendMessage...oops

Comment: There really isn't a "tradeoff" to speak of with AsyncTask, and the only place I use a raw Thread these days is when I'm spinning of a task that doesn't need to update the UI when it finishes in any way.  I actulally really recommend reading the source code to AsyncTask if you're trying to understand threads and handlers, too.

Answer (score 1):

Handler's post method requires a Runnable object in parameter, and scheduling execution of that runnable block.  Instead you can use Handler.sendEmptyMessage() or Handler.sendMessage() to send a message to Handler. SO change your code to following:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
               _mResults = _interpreter.executeExpression("startup;",_mHandler);
                Message msg= _mHandler.obtainMessage();
                msg.obj= _mResults;
               _mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
           }
       };
```